# user_followers() method not working in Instagrapi

Tags: python, instagrapi

If I try:

```
cl.user_followers(target_user_id, 1)
```

I can fetch the only first follower all the time, If I try fetch all followers I thing Instagram does not allow. I would be appreciated if any help.

This:

```
followers = cl.user_followers(target_user_id)['users']
```

Causes the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\public.py", line 136, in _send_public_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%225947509596%22%2C%22include_reel%22%3Atrue%2C%22fetch_mutual%22%3Afalse%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22QVFCVFdDRWpiR2VaOWViUHVTeTBUelZGYkpqeVlWUHlpQVJFalNRSTlDUWc0NGFPTGZjdm9XQnoxRWtzSDJXakhHblR0QmFvbC16c3ZzcnRLOGNER2ZsLQ%3D%3D%22%7D&query_hash=5aefa9893005572d237da5068082d8d5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 781, in user_followers
    users = self.user_followers_gql(user_id, amount)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 686, in user_followers_gql
    users, _ = self.user_followers_gql_chunk(str(user_id), amount)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 652, in user_followers_gql_chunk
    data = self.public_graphql_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\public.py", line 216, in public_graphql_request
    body_json = self.public_request(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\public.py", line 97, in public_request
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\public.py", line 74, in public_request
    return self._send_public_request(url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\public.py", line 169, in _send_public_request
    raise ClientError(e, response=e.response)
instagrapi.exceptions.ClientError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%225947509596%22%2C%22include_reel%22%3Atrue%2C%22fetch_mutual%22%3Afalse%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22QVFCVFdDRWpiR2VaOWViUHVTeTBUelZGYkpqeVlWUHlpQVJFalNRSTlDUWc0NGFPTGZjdm9XQnoxRWtzSDJXakhHblR0QmFvbC16c3ZzcnRLOGNER2ZsLQ%3D%3D%22%7D&query_hash=5aefa9893005572d237da5068082d8d5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\private.py", line 313, in _send_private_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/5947509596/followers/?max_id=&count=10000&rank_token=58645670417_39b50b64-a823-4634-a21a-71121ec79a3c&search_surface=follow_list_page&query=&enable_groups=true

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 785, in user_followers
    users = self.user_followers_v1(user_id, amount)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 752, in user_followers_v1
    users, _ = self.user_followers_v1_chunk(str(user_id), amount)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\user.py", line 714, in user_followers_v1_chunk
    result = self.private_request(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\private.py", line 461, in private_request
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\private.py", line 446, in private_request
    self._send_private_request(endpoint, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\private.py", line 387, in _send_private_request
    raise ClientError(e, response=e.response, **last_json)
instagrapi.exceptions.ClientError: Please wait a few minutes before you try again.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Facebook removed a bunch of functionalities as a way to clamp down on bots. You're not doing anything wrong; the API is intentionally and severely crippled.